# Coordinate systems from AutoCAD to QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, autocad

I am having issues bringing an AutoCAD drawing into QGIS. I currently use AutoCAD with Carlson (surface mining and civil modules). My current workflow for maps is this...
Import points using Lat/Long.
Use the "Adjust Coordinates" command to convert from Lat/Long to the state plane of that particular job.
Do my drawings I need to in CAD.

I would then like to visualize my drawing in QGIS. I know this is possible because a surveyor sent me his .dwg the other day, I saved it as a .dxf, and dragged and dropped into QGIS and it went to the correct location.

When I try this with my drawings, I cannot get it to show in the correct location. I can get it close (a couple hundred miles) by messing with different CRS.

I don't know if it's not working because of how I am importing the data into CAD, or exporting it from CAD, or importing to QGIS, or what.

I am using QGIS 3.8.1-Zanzibar and AutoCAD 2020.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had tried all the CRS in Alabama;
NAD27/Alabama East
NAD83/Alabama East
NAD83(2011)/Alabama East
NAD83(HARN)/Alabama East
NAD83(NSRS2007)Alabama East

None of those worked, but the one that actually worked, and took a little bit to find;
NAD_1983_StatePlane_Alabama_East_FIPS_0101_Feet (ESPG:102629)